# Plot graph year wise on x axis

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, analytics, data-analysis

I need to print a bar graph or any other graph with year on x-axis and suicide no on y axis.

[[image: Sample DataFrame[1]]

```
(df.pivot_table(
    index=df.year,
    columns='suicides_no',
    aggfunc='size').plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, colormap='dark2', width=0.2)
)
```

but its not printing what I want. For instance, a single color bar has different value.

[image]

Any other way to print the graph? Or any way to set the color coding of bar in perfect way?

Comment: use matplotlibs `LinearSegmentedColormap`. Check out one of my other answers on a similar topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61514549/9177877. You can display the graph by adding `%matplotlib inline`

Answer (score 0):

When applying pivot_table your index needs to be reset to be used in your plot.
You need to identify the name `cat` for the variable you want to stack over

```
df.pivot_table(
    values='suicides_no',
    index='year',
    columns='cat',
    aggfunc=np.sum).reset_index().plot(x='year',kind='bar', stacked=True)
```